# How to increase following limit per hour on Instagram? is there any other ways to following people more than its limit

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How to increase following limit per hour on Instagram? is there any other ways to increase following peoples more than its limit.

**Can we increase by using multiple application?**

Comment: I'm assuming there's a limit for a reason and it would either be against their ToC or would generally be unwanted by them? 

They won't have put a limit in place for no reason.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561917/should-i-get-a-new-access-token-for-every-user-instagram

Comment: It's Limit is 5000 per hours.

http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask your users to log into their Instagram account, and authorize your app, then you can make 5000 requests per hour per user:

http://instagram.com/developer/limits/

If you just use your key, you are limited to 5000 requests per hour, no matter how many users you have.

Comment: Yes  , but i am saying is there any other ways?

Answer (score -1):

> But I'm worried, what if this token expires?

AFAIK, Instagram accesstokens don't expire currently.

**Note:** [From Instagram documents.](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/)

Note that we do not include an expiry time. Our access_tokens have no explicit expiry, though your app should handle the case that either the user revokes access or we expire the token after some period of time. In this case, your response’s meta will contain an “error_type=OAuthAccessTokenError”. In other words: do do not assume your access_token is valid forever.

> Should I authorize the app each time the token expires?

At the moment, you do not need to do that, as token does not expire. As and when the token expires in future, a corresponding warning or error code and message will be sent to you, which you need to handle.

> what can I do to have my app always pulling data from account without
>   my participation?

You can try following:

1. Use sharedpreference to store the accesstoken.
2. First time when you try to fetch data that needs accesstoken(Authenticated requests), first check in the sharedpreference whether the accesstoken is stored or not.
   if yes then you don't need to login, just use that accesstoken. If you don't have the accesstoken in preference then do the login using instagram credentials, get the accesstoken and then share it in shared preference and use that for subsequent requests.
3. You can provide instagram logout option in which you just need to clear the accesstoken from sharedprefernce.

Hope this is helpful to you.